# Finding Jordan basis of a matrix $(4\times 4)$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I'm facing a problem finding a Jordan basis for this ($4 \times 4$) matrix:
$$\left(\begin{matrix}3&-1&1&7\\9&-3&-7&-1\\0&0&4&-8\\0&0&2&-4\end{matrix}\right)$$

I know that the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^4=0$ and it's minimal polynomial is: $x^2$. This means that $(A-0I)^2=0$. Also the Jordan form for this matrix is
$$\left(\begin{matrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$ But I'm facing problems in the general procedure to compute the basis for such a matrix?

Comment: You can find one linearly independent eigenvector and three generalized eigenvectors. Look up "chaining" + eigenvectors. For example, http://www.ms.uky.edu/~lee/amspekulin/jordan_canonical_form.pdf

Comment: Very useful and clear document. Was very helpful!

Comment: @Misha take also a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2557595/making-matrix-upper-triangular-by-finding-jordan-normal-form/2557722#2557722

Comment: @Misha Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, the minimal polynomial is not $\lambda^2$, and it seems to me that Ben's row reduction is wrong.

We have that the characteristic polynomial is $p(\lambda)=\lambda^4$, so, we already know that the jordan matrix will only have the value $0$ on the main diagonal.

Now we want to find the kernel of $(A-0I)=A$, so, reducing matrix $A$, we get

$$\pmatrix{
3&-1&1&7\\
9&-3&-7&-1\\
0&0&4&-8\\
0&0&2&-4} \leadsto
\pmatrix{
3&-1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0}
$$

Solving the system is not difficult,
$$
\pmatrix{
3&-1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0}
\cdot
\pmatrix{
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4}
=
\pmatrix{
0\\
0\\
0\\
0}
$$
we get, $x_3=x_4=0$ and $3x_1=x_2$, if $x_1=1$, then $x_2=3$, then the base of the kernel is given by the vector, $(1,3,0,0)$. From this, we conclude that the form of jordan has only one block, so it is of the form,

$$\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

as the exponent of the minimal polynomial can be given by the size of the largest block, we have that the minimal polynomial is $p_m(\lambda)=\lambda^4$

You can go on and find the Jordan base, as follows:

You want to find a vector $v$, so that, $A^3v,A^2v,Av,v$, they are all non-null. Calculating the exponents, we obtain,

$$A^2=\pmatrix{
0&0&28&-14\\
0&0&0&126\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0}
\qquad
A^3=\pmatrix{
0&0&84&-168\\
0&0&252&-504\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0}
$$

note that $e_3$ and $e_4$ are suitable vectors for what we want (because the third and fourth columns do not cancel and $A^4$ is the null matrix), let's choose $e_4$. So,

$$A^3e_4=(-168,-504,0,0)\qquad A^2e_4=(-14,126,0,0)\qquad Ae_4=(7,-1,-8,-4)$$

this way a Jordan base is

$$\{(0,0,0,1),(7,-1,-8,-4),(-14,126,0,0),(-168,-504,0,0)\}$$

it is not a *pretty* base, but this is a way to resolve the exercise quickly. We have so,

$$P=
\pmatrix{
0&7&-14&-168\\
0&-1&126&-504\\
0&-8&0&0\\
1&-4&0&0}
$$

And you can see that this [solves](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0%2C7%2C-14%2C-168%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C126%2C-504%7D%2C%7B0%2C-8%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C-4%2C0%2C0%7D%7D%5E%28-1%29%7B%7B3%2C-1%2C1%2C7%7D%2C%7B9%2C-3%2C-7%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C4%2C-8%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C2%2C-4%7D%7D%7B%7B0%2C7%2C-14%2C-168%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C126%2C-504%7D%2C%7B0%2C-8%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C-4%2C0%2C0%7D%7D) the problem, $J=P^{-1}AP$.

Answer (score 1):

Since:

$J$ is obtained by $A$ from a similarity transfomation $$P^{-1}AP=J$$

> $P$ can be found **solving the system** 
>   $$AP=PJ$$

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the tips, i manage to solve it. The basis is

$$\left(\begin{matrix}-7 & 0 & 3 & 1\\-1 & 0 & 9 & 0\\-8 & 0 & 0 & 0\\-4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$$ And $P^{-1}AP=J$

Comment: Could you give a hint on how to solve it? I am facing a similar problem. Just cannot solve it.